# Power series of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, power-series, analytic-functions

Suppose $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n$ for $|z|<r$, where $r>0$.
Also $f(z)$ is continuous on $|z|\leq r$.
My question is whether the function $f(z)$ is analytic in some "big" disk $|z|<R(R>r)$?
I think the answer is "yes",  because there is no singularity on $|z|=r$, so it can be analytic in a big disk! But I can not give strict proof.
Or some theorem which I do not know can imply my question!
Any help or hint  will welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n^2}$. Then $f$ is continuous in the region $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,|z|\leqslant1\}$. And analytic on $D(0,1)$. However, you cannot extend it to an analytic function on a larger circle.

Comment: Why your given function is continuous on $|z|=1$?

Comment: Because the series converges uniformly (just apply the Weierstrass $M$-test) and each $\frac{z^n}{n^2}$ is continuous.

Comment: One more question @ José Carlos Santos : In my situation, does the series converge uniformly on the closed disk $|z|\leq 1$? Or some further condition needed for the uniform convergent?

Comment: @Riemann Yes, the series converges uniformly on that closed disk, by the Weierstrasss $M$-test.